# COM control on .NET Form?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

If I use a COM control such as a button on a .NET form, are there any risks?

I don't want the form crashing at some random point in the future.

What are the risks and consequences of adding a COM control to a .NET form?

Comment: What does the button do that you couldn't use a .NET WinForm button instead?

Comment: I think he was just searching for an example and this wasn't a specific thing he was doing.

Comment: There's really only one consideration: who do you call when the COM code misbehaves.  A universal consideration for *any* code that you don't have the source code for and can't fix.  If you don't have a good answer for that, and it is increasingly rare to have one, then using such a control isn't a very good idea.

Answer (score 3):

There are no particular risks, but COM objects are a bit more sensitive to cross-threading issues if you try to access its methods on a different thread from the one that spawned the object (same as Winforms)

Other thing to bear in mind is that if your application is built as AnyCPU and you use 32-bit COM components, it may fail on a 64 bit system. So make sure the build target matches that of any COM components you're using (this isn't true in all cases since .Net produces managed wrappers for COM components, but it is something to be aware of)